# Setting date in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have a code to identify current date and its set to `End_period`. How can I set 60 days before the `End_period` to the `Start_period`?

```
var End_period = ee.Date(new Date().getTime())
var Start_period = ee.Date('2020-01-18')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `advance()` method on your date object.

```
var End_period = ee.Date(new Date().getTime());

var Start_period = End_period.advance(-60,'day');
```

this will "advance" your date -60 days.